Grounding a single receptacle
The electrical receptacle (outlet) for my refrigerator is a 3 prong that is really just a 3 prong that’s replaced a 2 wire older receptacle, meaning only black/white no ground. For a legit ground can I run a separate ground wire to the cast iron sewer line or a grounding rod just outside the wall, or is my only choice to run an entire new line from the panel?

Can you get back to the wires connecting your existing grounding system to the panel, or to a different grounded circuit for that matter?

Newer code does allow for a separate ground wire.

Is the receptacle in a metal box or a plastic box? If it is in a metal box, you may find that either there is a ground wire but connected outside the box instead of inside the box (not to code, but it will work) or metal conduit or armored cable (which is sometimes good enough, depends on the type) carrying the hot/neutral wires to the box and acting as a ground wire.

Sewer line: NO.  Pipes are not wires and you'll destroy the pipe with galvanic corrosion (caused by the current).  Also, any maintenance to that pipe will certainly be done in plastic so that severs the ground.
Ground rod: NO.  If dirt was a good conductor, we wouldn't bother to mine copper!  That connection would not be able to flow enough current to "clear a fault" - i.e. trip the breaker if hot shorts to ground.  Instead, it would just sit there energizing the chassis of the fridge, the ground rod, and the dirt immediately around the ground rod.  Now a GFCI receptacle could make this still not legal but less bad, because the dirt can probably flow 5mA, enough to trip the GFCI. But nobody wants GFCIs on fridges.
However, you can deploy any of the methods in NEC 250.130(C), which simply call for running a suitably sized ground wire (#14 for 15A circuit, #12 for 20A) to any other junction box with that size or larger ground going back to the panel.  Alternately, you can use a split-bolt to clamp onto the Grounding Electrode wire - the bare wire running from main panel to ground rods.


Some readers, especially non-US'ers (like myself) don't understand your last sentence. 2. "to... larger ground going back to the panel" <- where and how do you recommend OP have their grouding wire connect to the other grounding wire? And how large is "larger"?


@einpoklum typically this means connecting a new ground wire from the outlet that's missing one, to another outlet that is properly grounded.  Probably need to pigtail the new ground to the existing one.  Obviously, you need to follow any wire protection requirements (e.g. you can't generally run exposed wires outside a wall).

@einpoklum that was only a summary of 250.130(C), which is where the matter is covered in full detail.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica: Summary of... what's that now? 8-|

you have to connect to the panel, but you don't need to connect directly to the panel, you may instead connect to the grounding conductor of some other outlet.

Same question as for Harper: How and where do you suggest the connection to another grounding conductor be made?

I can't see your situation, only what has been written. Look around.  connecting back to the panel is sufficient. but a short-cut may be possible.
